# "Make sure you configure your 'user.email' and 'user.name' in git" when trying to push to git lab

Tags: git, gitlab

I keep getting the same message when I try to push to my git lab account:

> "Make sure you configure your 'user.email' and 'user.name' in git".

I've already done

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"

git config --global user.email "johndoe@email.com"
```

And I've checked w/

```
git remote -v
```

Anyone have any ideas on what else I can do?

Comment: Some information that might be helpful for troubleshooting: (1) What OS are you working on? (2) What Git client software are you using?

Comment: I guess that, if you have already committed, you should recommit so that the authors are corrected on the revision that you already made. If it's a single revision, you might do `git commit --amend --author="john doe"` (correct John Doe for your name). Then it might work.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I'm not sure what client software it is... maybe git 2.20.1? Sorry, I'm new to git.

Comment: This is what i got when i did git commit --amend -- author = "john doe"           error: pathspec 'author' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '=' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'amturrietta' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: @Ashley, it's `--amend --author="Ashley Turrieta"`, I guess

Comment: Run the terminal (or git bash) from the directory he indicates and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 106):

Make sure you run this commands

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"

git config --global user.email "johndoe@email.com"
```

In the terminal. In this directory -I´m a Windows user-: C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Had the same issue. Solved running those commands there

Comment: I had this just now. I suspect it was caused by me trying to free up space all over my PC. Probably deleted some settings file.  This fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You should see that error message on git commit, not git push, [as seen here](http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/blog/solved-visual-studio-code-make-sure-you-configure-your-user-name-and-user-email-in-git).

Make sure to type those commands in a CMD session *not* launched as "Administrator", but as your regular Windows user account.

You can check if that setting is set by going into your repository, and typing:

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr:

1. Ensure git's `user.name` and `user.email` are set globally:
   `git config --global --edit`
   (in the file that opens, there may be already two commented lines with your username and email; just uncomment them and save)
2. Then commit with `reset-author` to force the new credentials:
   `git commit --amend --reset-author`

---

I encountered the same error when staging files on a repo hosted on a remote server (SSH connection). The error appeared in Visual Studio Code's `Source Control` tab after pressing the `Commit` UI button (which, in background, attempts to stage all and then commit).

I then tried to manually stage from the terminal of Visual Studio Code via:

```
git add -A
```

And no error appeared. I then tried committing from terminal via `git commit -a -m "some commit comment"`, and these instructions popped up:

```
username@machine:~$ git commit -a -m "some commit comment"

[main 816910d] some commit comment
 Committer: username <someEmailAddress>
Your name and e-mail address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

    git config --global --edit

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

I then did `git config --global --edit` and in the file that opened I simply uncommented the two lines that were pre-filled with username and email, then saved the file.

I then tried doing `git commit --amend --reset-author` but it returned some other errors. I ignored them and proceded to commit normally, which worked. From there onwards, problems solved, I also could use Visual Studio Code UI to handle source control without errors.

Comment: i tried all sorts of git config commands but my error remained the same (_Make sure you configure your 'user.email' and 'user.name' in git_). I tried setting user.name and user.email with the global flag, in the programfiles/git/bin, nothing worked, apart from @alelom's suggestion, thank you!:
(1) Ensure git user.name & user.email are set globally:

`$ git config --global --edit`

(2) Then commit with reset-author to somehow force the new credentials:

`$ git commit --amend --reset-author`. *Problem solved :D*

Answer (score 2):

Finally i solved for me with controlling the system-configuration (not repository or user configuration):

```
git config --system user.name 
git config --system user.email
```

the email was correct, but no name registered. So:

```
git config --system user.name "MyName"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. On Windows, the solution was running Command Prompt as administrator.

Comment: ...and doing what?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34806440)

Answer (score -2):

Simply install GitHub desktod. That will solve your issue remember to log in first on the GitHub desktop. Then restart your terminal (Or vs code) then try to do the same.