# Why is the Commit operation taking forever in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When trying to 'commit' files the process just loads and loads but never completes.

[image]

These are the steps I followed:

1. I installed "Git"
2. Created a repository for my files and then put some random files in there
3. Opened VS Code and opened my repository folder
4. Navigated to "Source Control"
5. Staged my documents (I didn't actually make any changes to the files but I just wanted to test it out since it's my first time using the tool).
6. Clicked "Commit"
7. When I clicked "Commit" I got an error which read:

   > "Make sure you configure your 'user.name' and 'user.email' in git."
8. I found this link on Stack Overflow: ["Make sure you configure your 'user.email' and 'user.name' in git" when trying to push to git lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876421/make-sure-you-configure-your-user-email-and-user-name-in-git-when-trying-t), and using that link, I opened the terminal and typed:

   ```
   git config --global user.name "My name"

   git config --global user.email "myemail"
   ```

   Please see the image below:

   [image]
9. I then clicked 'Commit', it began running but it just loaded indefinitely and never completed.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?.

I really tried to find a solution online. People suggested updating Visual Studio Code, fortunately mine is already up to date.

Comment: ¿Did you actually type any commit message? ¿What happens if you execute `git commit -m 'message'` instead of clicking? Or `git log`

Comment: Just read your message now. I was actually coming on here to say that I solved it after  typing a message before clicking 'commit'. Since you made the suggestion before I solved it please post it on here as an answer so I could accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea why Git does this. It happens to me occasionally, but there are some solutions.

First, restart Visual Studio Code. Then try to **commit & push** again. If it still doesn't work, restart it again and this time, **don't forget to write a message while committing.**

You can also do

```
git commit -m 'message'
```

as it sometimes works. You can try that too.

I mostly experience this issue when I forget to write a message while committing or when there is an update to Git.

Comment: Making sure to write a commit message should be the first thing to check.

Comment: "*I have no idea why Git does this.*" It's also probably not Git, but a VS Code problem, in that it should show some warning if you forgot to add a commit message and the UI is waiting for you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I forgot to write a commit message.

When git is run without a commit message it will open an editor to allow for longer messages, thus leading to it hanging forever.

If on Linux you can open htop, search for git and kill the process, not sure how that would be done on Windows.

Comment: Yeah it was the commit message

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is not really "hanging"; it's just giving you a second chance to enter a commit message if you forgot to provide one in the space provided by the commit button.  Git works this way from the command line as well.

In this case, VS Code fills buffer with a default commit message with a list of changed files spelled out. I usually delete list, but you may opt to keep and augment it for a more explanatory and detailed per-file message.

When you are satisfied with your commit message, click on the not-at-all-obvious, barely visible checkbox in the upper right corner of the window that let's you accept (or reject) your message.

[tiny check button to approve your commit message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwcjx.png)

Answer (score -2):

The solution for this problem is to sync VSCode with GitHub:

1. Click the Settings icon in the bottom left
2. Enable "Settings Sync is On"

[image]